# Java String Object .Equals not working as intended

Tags: java, android

I am pulling my hair out over what should be a simple problem

I am trying to compare two string objects using .equals but they do not match

```
if (folderJobNumber.toUpperCase().equals(fileJobNumber.toUpperCase())) {
                dostuff;
            }
```

Each string object is showing as "Y019/" in debug
Please note that for both i had used substring to get their value as per below

```
String folderJobNumber = folderLocation.substring(folderLocation.length() - 5).trim();
String fileJobNumber = file.getName().substring(0,4) + "/".trim();
```

Please see screenshot below of each variable in debug

[image]

I have a feeling that the problem is this value which appears to be a char array of the data before using substring.

Thankyou in advanced for any light that you may shed on the problem

Comment: Aside: `String.equalsIgnoreCase` would be better.

Comment: What values are displayed with System.out.println(folderJobNumber + fileJobNumber);

Comment: It often helps to look at the output of `Arrays.toString(str.toCharArray())` for the two strings when you can't see why they're not comparing as equal. It shows up problems like different characters which *look* the same, but have different numeric values.

Comment: Also: `file.getName().substring(0,4) + "/".trim()` means `file.getName().substring(0,4) + ("/".trim())` - so the `.trim()` is redundant.

Comment: Thankyou Andy and pruntlar. I will be testing shortly but the device is on charge at the moment.

Comment: Why is the hashCode zero?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` if you just want to compare the two strings.

```
if (folderJobNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(fileJobNumber)) {
                dostuff;
}
```

Comment: You *can*; but it's not clear why it wouldn't be working using `toUpperCase` and `equals` if this approach would work instead.

Comment: Because value.length is different for both Strings. In this case equalsIgnoreCase will method will fail as well.

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit `value.length` isn't used in string comparison. `count` is.

Comment: Not according to OpenJDK http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit it also doesn't have a `count` field in that version; so OP isn't using that version. (I believe the count/offset existed until [Java 6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/String.java/#119), then was removed in [Java 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#111)).

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit this is interesting and at first sight appears that it could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. JDK 6 compares from count. It is probably failing due to non equal character somewhere. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/3d2f9f6b0f09/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

Answer (score 0):

> String folderJobNumber =
>   folderLocation.substring(folderLocation.length() - 5).trim(); String
>   fileJobNumber = file.getName().substring(0,4) + "/".trim();

And looking at the debug screenshot, folderJobNumber is char[56], so I assume that is where the problem is...I am not sure how the folderLocation string was obtained, assuming it is in this fashion

```
char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
     String str = new String(data);
```

I would try

```
String folderJobNumber = folderLocation.trim().substring(folderLocation.length() - 5)
```